# Giving device address SRF10

Tags: c++

I have problem with program. I don't know which method or function (I have problem with name) "measurementSensor" is good. I wrote first code to give address device.

```
    class I2CConnection{

     private:
       int fd;                  
       char*  fileName;     
       int flag;
       int isOpen;
       int currentAddress;

    public:

       I2CConnection(char *name,int flag = O_RDWR){
       this->fileName = name;
       this->isOpen = 0;
       }

    int send(char* buf[],unsigned int size){
        if((write(this->fd,buf,size)) < size){
            printf("Error writing to i2c slave\n");
        }else{
            return(size);
        }   
    }
    int recive(char* buf[],unsigned int size){
        if((read(this->fd,buf,size)) <size){
            printf("Error writing to i2c slave\n"); 
        }else{
            return(size);
        }
    }
    int connectTo(int address){
        if(ioctl(this->fd,I2C_SLAVE,address) < 0){
            printf("Unable to get bus access to talk to slave\n");
            return(0);
        }else{
            this->currentAddress = address;
            return(1);
        }
    }
      int openConnection(){
      if((fd = open(fileName, O_RDWR)) < 0){
          printf("Failed to open i2c port\n");
          this->isOpen = 0;
      }else{
        this->isOpen = 1;
      }
      return(this->isOpen)
      }

     int closeConnection(){
       if(close(fd)==0){
          this->isOpen = 0;
       }else{
          this->isOpen = 1;
       }
       return(!this->isOpen);
     }

     ~I2CConnection(){
        if ( this->isOpen){
          closeConnection();
    }
     }
    }
    class SonicSensor{

      private:
          int address;
          unsigned int units;
          I2CConnection* conn;
          unsigned int value;

      public:
       SonicSensor(I2CConnection* c,int addr){
            this->address = addr;
            this->conn = c;
        }
       void changeUnits(int u){
             this->units = u;
       }
       unsigned int measurementSensor(char* buf[]){
        buf[0] = 0;
        buf[1] = 0x51;
        c.send(buf,2);
        buf[0] = 0xA0;
        c.send(buf,1);
        buf[0] = 0xAA;
        c.send(buf,1);
        buf[0] = 0xA5;
        c.send(buf,1);
        buf[0] = 0xF2;
        c.send(buf,1);
    }
      ~SonicSensor(){
    }
};
```

The problem is the error: invalid conversion from int to char*. I can't found solved for this error.

Comment: First of all you should make a _minimal_ testcase, when you need to debug a problem. http://sscce.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be working with arrays of bytes, not arrays of pointers-to-bytes. Unless your target platform uses 8-bit pointers, you will end up writing pointer-sized values to your I2C device instead of single bytes as intended. On a 32-bit system, for the first command instead of sending two bytes (`00` and `51`) you would actually send 8 bytes (`00 00 00 00` and `00 00 00 51`).

Your `I2CConnection` methods `send` and `receive` should be declared as:

```
int send(const char* buf, unsigned int size)

int receive(char* buf, unsigned int size)
```

Likewise, your `SonicSensor` class `measurementSensor` method does not appear to need an input argument, so it could be done as:

```
unsigned int measurementSensor() {
    char buf[2];
    ...
```